# iOS: minimum image resources necessary for ios application using size classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, xcode6

This question might be a duplicate, but I couldn't find any reasonable answer.

I am developing an app that supports all iOS devices, for which I have to import image resources for every device.
If I use image optimizer, it will destroy quality of images.
Currently my app consists of iPhone 5, 6, 6+, iPad and iPad retina images, which costs me about 20 MB space in my application.
How can I reduce this size?
 E.g. by removing iPhone 5 or iPhone 6 images, will the application work fine or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will all entirely depend on the design of your application. @3x graphics are for the iPhone 6+ only (for now), and the resolution on the device is so high some users *might* not notice that the @3x graphics are missing. You might also be able to "re-use" some of your iPhone graphics for the iPad (for example you could use the iPhone @2x graphics for the iPad non-retina). But again, depends on your graphics design.

Comment: To answer you question about whether the application will fork fine or not: The application will always select the best image for the device resolution automatically (If you follow the naming conventions). It will almost certainly "work fine" even if you remove all but one set of images, but it might not look so good on all devices :-)

Comment: @Jespar Thanks, I tested images only with 3x images on iPhone 5 real device, it worked fine for me..
But I don't have an iPad or Retina iPad thats the reason of asking, weather i remove non Retina  or not..
On simulator, it works fine.
Sometimes in general  it varies on simulator and a real device..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you use this images, but
If you want reduce the size of your app there are, for me, two solution.

- Check if the size of your images are not too big (the size of your `UIImageView` x2 will be enough).
- Get the images by downloading the right image and store it in the device.

Comment: I am asking about image resources.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to store iPhone 5,6,6+ startup images just to disable scaling.

- Remove redundant orientations from startup images.
- Try to use [ImageOptim](https://imageoptim.com) to minimise png images. It uses lossless optimisations.
- Try to use lossy optimisations for images if they are still too big.
- If you use clean background in your app, save startup images with only background colour without UI, and make sure that app start fast. It will look OK.

Comment: my app has custom backgrounds and so I am using them..
I have programatically created resources where i could..
I understand startup images are much more important. what about others?
If i skip other iphone 6  and ipad images(not ipad retina )
will it work fine?

Comment: Actually, you can just use a XIB for the startup image. With the correct layout that could save you quite a lot of space. Select File->New->File, then select User Interface -> Launch Screen.